# How to save query as a table and store in redshift via Lambda Function in AWS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I am writing a lambda function in aws thats calling on data from redshift. Purpose of this function is to run each day and sends out notifications (emails) of the output from this function (in this case - I want it to be a table).

Here is my current function. I am able to see the list of rows from the query output but now I want to save that in a table format or least print out the full table/output. Very new to AWS so I was wondering how do I store it as a new table in redshift/or anywhere else in AWS so I can send it to ppl?

Code:

```
import json
import psycopg2
import boto3

credential = {
    'dbname' : 'main',
    'host_url' : 'dd.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    'port' : '5439',
    'user' : 'private',
    'password' : '12345678'
}


redshift_role = {
    'dev': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:15131234566:function:test_function'
}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    #client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
    
    conn_string = "dbname='{}' port='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'"\
    .format(credential['dbname'], credential['port'], credential['user'], credential['password'], credential['host_url'])
    
    con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    
    sql_query = """with
    tbl as (
    select    
          case 
            when (sa.parentid like '001i0000023STBY%' or sa.ultimate_parent_account__c like '001i0000023STBY%') --Parent OR Ultimate Parent is <Department of Defense> 
            then sa.id 
            else 
              coalesce(sa.ultimate_parent_account__c, sa.parentid, sa.id) end as cust_id,
            (select name from salesforce.account where id=cust_id) as cust_name,
            sa.name as acct_name,
            sa.id as acct_id,
            sa.parentid,
            (select name from salesforce.account where id=sa.parentid) as par_name,
            (select name from salesforce.account where id=sa.ultimate_parent_account__c) as ult_par_name,
            so.id as opp_id,
            so.name as opp_name,
            so.stagename as stg_name,
            so.type as opp_type,
            so.Manager_Commit__c as mgr_commit,
            so.renewal_risk__c as opp_risk,
            so.isclosed as cls,
            so.finance_date__c as fin_date,
            DATEPART(QUARTER,so.finance_date__c) as Q,
            DATEPART(QUARTER,so.closedate) as Q_cls,
            DATEPART(QUARTER,so.subscription_start_date__c) as Q_ren_due,
            so.Total_NARR__c  as arr,
            so.NARR__c as fin_nacv,
            so.churn__c as fin_churn,
            so.Renewal_Amount__c as ren_amt,
            so.Available_to_Renew_ARR__c as avl_ren_arr,
            so.estimated_narr__c  as nacv,
            so.bi_detect_nacv__c as bi_detect,
            so.bi_recall_nacv__c as bi_recall,
            so.bi_stream_nacv__c as bi_stream,
            so.bi_dfaws_nacv__c as bi_dfaws,
            so.bi_o365_nacv__c as bi_o365,
            so.bi_services_nacv__c as bi_svcs,
            sp.name as pr_name,
            sp.family as pr_family,
            sp.sbqq__subscriptiontype__c as pr_type, 
            sol.product_code__c as oli_code,
            sol.sbqq__quoteline__c as qli_id,
            sol.quantity as qty,
            sca.serial__c as ca_name,
            (select name from salesforce.product2 where id = sca.product__c ) as ca_pr_name,
            sca.mode_updater__c as ca_mode,
            sca.updater_last_seen__c as ca_last_seen,
            sca.software_version__c as ca_sw_version,
            sca.total_hosts__c as ca_tot_hosts,
            sca.active_hosts__c as ca_active_hosts,
            sca.X95_Host_Total__c as ca_x95_hosts_tot,
            sca.traffic__c as ca_traffic,
            sca.uiconfig__c as ca_uiconfig
    from
            salesforce.opportunity so
        join 
            salesforce.account sa on
            so.accountid = sa.id
        join salesforce.user su on
          so.ownerid = su.id
        join salesforce.opportunitylineitem sol on
          so.id = sol.opportunityid
        join salesforce.product2 sp on
          sol.product2id = sp.id
        join salesforce.customasset__c sca on
          so.id = sca.opportunity__c
        where 
            so.isdeleted = false
            and sa.isdeleted = false
            and sol.isdeleted = false
      order by
          Q
    )
    
  
  select * from 
  (select
        tbl.acct_name as acct,  
        tbl.ca_name,
        tbl.ca_pr_name,
        tbl.ca_mode,
        date(tbl.ca_last_seen) as ca_last_seen,
        tbl.ca_sw_version,
        tbl.ca_tot_hosts,
        tbl.ca_active_hosts,
        tbl.ca_x95_hosts_tot,
        tbl.ca_traffic,
        tbl.ca_uiconfig
    from
        tbl
      where
        tbl.stg_name like 'Closed Won%'
        and tbl.arr is not null
      group by
      tbl.acct_name,
      tbl.opp_id,
      tbl.ca_name,
      tbl.ca_pr_name,
      tbl.ca_mode,
      tbl.ca_last_seen,
      tbl.ca_sw_version,
      tbl.ca_tot_hosts,
      tbl.ca_active_hosts,
      tbl.ca_x95_hosts_tot,
      tbl.ca_traffic,
      tbl.ca_uiconfig) df 
  
  WHERE ca_last_seen >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())"""
    
cur.execute(sql_query)
   
    
    with con.cursor() as cur:
      rows = []
      cur.execute(sql_query)
      for row in cur:
          rows.append(row)
      print(rows)
    
    con.close()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

### Update

I included a write portion to tmp directory but am having trouble writing to my s3 bucket as it leads to a timeout error.

Updated portion of code below:

```
with con.cursor() as cur:
    # Enter the query that you want to execute
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    for row in cur:
      res = cur.fetchall()
      print(res)
      #Save the Query results to a CSV file
      fp = open('/tmp/Processlist.csv', 'w')
      myFile = csv.writer(fp)
      myFile.writerows(res)
      fp.close()
    #s3.upload_file('/tmp/Processlist.csv', 'data-lake-020192', 'Processlist.csv')
  #con.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  The first and least efficient is to insert data into a table using INSERT INTO  VALUES (...).  This provides the data as part of the SQL and therefore is processed by the query compiler, moved from the leader to the compute nodes, and then stored in the table.  This process is inefficient, potentially stresses the leader node, and is generally frowned upon.  However, if you are only loading a small number of rows and it run infrequently (like when the database is generally lightly loaded) then this can work fine.  Just remember there is a limit to how long a SQL statement can be but if you are anywhere close to this you are likely loading too much data via this path.  100 rows of 5 columns should be ok.

The best way, but takes more coding, is to write the data out to an S3 file (or files if the data is large) and then COPY it into the desired table.  A CSV file is simple to generate and human readable.  This process also gives you a record of the table contents per day for any future need (debug, audit, etc.).

Alternatively you could just save the data to S3 and then use Redshift Spectrum to access the data from S3.  This may be a good choice for very large amounts of data and/or data that is rarely used.  In most cases I would expect that having the data native in Redshift (COPY from S3) is the way to go.

Coding any of these in lambda is straight forward - just make the calls to the services and issue the SQL as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Since this data is being stored in redshift originally, is there a way to use redshift api over s3 or is that the same thing? Would I essentially create an s3 bucket within the lambda function and then append the results (the query output) to that s3 file? Not sure how to write to an s3 file but seems pretty straight forward!

Comment: OK I think I see some base info would help.  The AWS APIs have calls for Redshift and for S3.  S3 is an object store and each objects is referenced by "bucket" and "key".  Likely you will make a bucket for your data to live and then code will make objects in the bucket by specifying "bucket" and "key".   Redshift has a SQL statement to UNLOAD data from the database and store it in S3.  This UNLOAD statement is kinda the opposite to the COPY statement.  Your Lambda would only need to issue the command to Redshift to UNLOAD a table's data to S3 objects - yes, multiple by default.

Comment: There are options to UNLOAD that can be used to make a single file (object) in S3 but the total data needs to be less than 5GB.  (parallel off)

Comment: Please reference updated code above. Awesome! This gave me a lot of good context. Upon further research - I added this code to save as a csv in the tmp directory. Is there any way to access that? I am having trouble writing this csv file to my s3 bucket as I get a 'timeout error'.

Comment: I don't see where you open the boto3 client for s3 - "s3_client = boto3.client('s3')".  I assume you have this somewhere possibly assigned to "s3".  Should look like https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file (if you want to use upload_file)

Comment: Yes - sorry its added above outside the function just forgot to add. Do you know why it is timing out? Does it have anything to do with bucket permissions?

Comment: Is the call timing out or the lambda?  How big is the file you are uploading?  Permissions are a possibility, not that they would hang but that your code wouldn't handle the exception well.  Using "try" and adding debug statements seems like the way to go.

Comment: I believe so. This is the error: errorMessage": "Connect timeout on endpoint URL: \"https://bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Processlist.csv\"". The csv is 3500 rows and 12 columns..not big at all

Comment: Is your lambda running in a VPC?  If so does this VPC have an s3 endpoint?  "bucket.s3.us-..." looks odd, like the bucket it is accessing is called "bucket".  This could be just bad error messaging as I see in your code your bucket is called "data-lake-020192".  Your lambda function should have a role attached that allows it to write to this bucket but if this was the issue I would expect a "permission denied" error.  My best guess is that you don't have a route from your lambda to s3 and need to add an s3 endpoint to your VPC.

Comment: yes it is connected to a public VPC so I can access it. I added the s3 bucket as a trigger that is paired to the function. Looks like I need to add the s3 info to the vpc as well. Thanks for your help!